# Application-defined or Object defined error when adding a average line using new series to a chart (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have a single data series to create chart after that , have to add an average line , getting an error at line "ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = ycord" as "application defined or object defined error" , checked and new series is getting created

```
Worksheets(sht).Activate

ycord = "=" & sht & "!$BF$" & cellposition
ydata = "=" & sht & "!$BF$" & cellposition + 1 & ":$BF$" & cellposition + 2 & ""
xdata = "=" & sht & "!$BE$" & cellposition + 1 & ":$BE$" & cellposition + 2 & ""

Range("A" & rowno & ":AF" & rowno).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'" & sht & "'!$A$" & rowno & ":$AF$" & rowno)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)
ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries


//receiving the error in below line at name


ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = ycord
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = ydata
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = xdata
With ActiveChart
  .Parent.Left = Range(chartcol & chartrow).Left
  .Parent.Top = Range(chartcol & chartrow).Top
End With
```

Comment: Use `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count` to find out how many items there are.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to simons comment found out had issues with spaces in the sheet name, corrected the spaces and the code wotked fine